# Initializing base class members in derived class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 classes: A (base) and B (derived). I need help with writing constructor for B where members of A  need to be initialized.

```
class A
    private:
        std::string name;
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    public:
        A(std::string n) : name(n) {};
        A(std::string n, int aa, int bb, int cc) : name(n), a(aa), b(bb),                                                 
                c(cc) {};
          ...
};

class B : public A {
    private:
        int d;
        int e;
    public:
        B(std::string n, int aa, int bb, int cc,
                   int dd, int ee) : A(n, aa, bb, cc) //here comes the question
        {
            d=dd; e=ee;
        }
};
```

In the second constructor of class B it initializes members of class A with given values aa,bb,cc; In case these values are not given I want class A to get random numbers for its members:

```
B(std::string n, int dd, int ee) : A(n, (rand%10)+1, (rand%10)+1,(rand%10)+1)
{
    d=dd;
    e=ee;
}
```

Is there a better way to implement it? In my actual example I have more members in A class and it's not convenient to use list initializer syntax.

P.S. Not sure presented variant will work properly since i need to include somewhere srand(time(NULL)) thing...

Comment: Casually formatted pseudocode. Btw, member initializer lists solve the naming problem and also `d==dd;`-like typos.

Comment: Also, you're not initializing `a`, `b`, `c` in `A(std::string n)` to a useful value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the random number generation into a constructor of `A`, e. g. by extending the first form to `A(std::string n, bool fillRandom = false)` and doing the generation when `fillRandom == true`. The call from `B` would look like

```
B(std::string n, int dd, int ee) : A(n, true) 
{ ...
```

Comment: `A(std::string n, bool fillRandom=false) : name(n)`
`{if (fillRandom)`
`{`
   `srand(time(NULL));  a=(rand%10)+1; b=(rand%10)+1; c=  (rand%10)+1;`
`}`
Would it look like this?

Answer (score 2):

You could also implement a (`protected`) constructor for A that initializes the members to random values and then call this in your constructor for B.

If you add a (protected) class to A (e.g. call it `RandomInit`) you can use this as a parameter to your newly created constructor to make the call unambigous. The class itself can be empty of course.

Comment: You mean, create anoher empty class and make it a member of class A? I don't realy understand, too new to OOP(

Comment: Yes, that was the idea - if you just write `class X{};` inside your class-definition for `A` you can define a constructor `A(string n, X)`. You don't even need to give this parameter a name, it just serves as a flag for "init with random values" and makes it a different constructor than the already existing one with only a string. Or you simply use a bool as Murphy suggested, much easier but then the "random initialization" will be public as well.